# Array Sorting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have created a function `defineDataArray()` to add data to my array, and it populates the array `tableData` as a 2-d array, with values taken from rows and cells of the web table body. I looped through with a for loop and was able to set all the variables in the array, but when I call my function to sort, the data cannot be added to the `tableData` array and sorted. I need to sort the `tableData` array using my dataSort2D() function. The dataSort2D() function is a premade function that is built-in, and not to be changed.

This is what I have so far:

```
"use strict";

/*   
   Global Variables:
   tableData
      A 2-dimensional array of the data found in the body of the web table
      
   dataCategories
      An array of the column titles found the head of the web table
      
   sortIndex
      The index number of the column by which the web table should be
      sorted where 0 = 1st column, 1 = 2nd column, etc.
      
   sortDirection
      A value indicating direction of the sorting where a value of 1 sorts 
      the data in ascending order and a value of -1 sorts the data in descending order
    
   
   
   Functions List:   
   defineDataArray()
      Extracts values from the body of the web table and stores them in the
      tableData array
      
   writeTableData()
      Writes the sorted data into the table rows and cells       
      
   defineColumns()
      Extracts values form the column heads of the web table and stores 
      them in the dataCategories array; also sets up the onclick event
      handlers for the column heads so that the table can be sorted by
      clicking a table heading cell.
           
   columnSort(e)
      Event handler function that sorts the table data when a column
      heading is clicked  
   
   dataSort2D(a, b)
      Compare function used to sort numeric and alphabetical data from
      a 2-dimensional array 
*/

// define global variables
var tableData = [];
var dataCategories = [];
var sortIndex = 0;
var sortDirection = 1;

// create Event Listener
window.addEventListener("load", function()
  {
    defineDataArray();
    writeTableData();
    defineColumns();
  }
);

function defineDataArray() 
{
  var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table.sortable tbody tr");

  for(var i = 0; i<tableRows.length; i++)
  {
    var rowCells = tableRows[i].children;
    var rowValues = new Array(rowCells.length);
    for(var j = 0; j<rowCells.length; j++)
    {
        rowValues[j] = rowCells[j].textContent;
    }
    tableData[i] = rowValues;
  }
  tableData.sort(dataSort2D);
}

function dataSort2D(a, b) {
   if (isNaN(parseFloat(a[sortIndex])) === false) {
      return (a[sortIndex] - b[sortIndex])*sortDirection;
   } else {
      var astring = a[sortIndex].toLowerCase();
      var bstring = b[sortIndex].toLowerCase();
           
      if (bstring > astring) return -sortDirection;
      if (bstring < astring) return sortDirection;
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: `... there is an error` ... what is the error?

Comment: @Paul T. the data cannot be added to the tableData array and sorted.